# Consecutive separators are ignored by BOOST / tokenizer

Tags: c++, boost

I am using BOOST / tokenizer to split a string.
It works fine for strings like "1,2,3", but when there are two or more consecutive separators, for example "1,,3,4", it returns "1", "3", "4".

Is there a way to tokenizer returns an empty  string "" instead of skip it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boost.Tokenizer's [`char_separator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm) class provides the option to output an empty token or to skip ahead with its `empty_tokens` parameter.  It defaults to `boost::drop_empty_tokens`, matching the behavior of `strtok()`, but can be told to output empty tokens by providing `boost::keep_empty_tokens`.

For example, with the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::string str = "1,,3,4";
  typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;
  boost::char_separator<char> sep(
      ",", // dropped delimiters
      "",  // keep delimiters
      boost::keep_empty_tokens); // empty token policy

  BOOST_FOREACH(std::string token, tokenizer(str, sep))
  {
    std::cout << "<" << token << "> ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
<1> <> <3> <4>
```

Answer (score 4):

I supposed that you have use the split function as below

```
string text = "1,,3,4";
list<string> tokenList;
split(tokenList, text, is_any_of(","));
BOOST_FOREACH(string t, tokenList)
{
  cout << t << "." << endl;
}
```

If you carefully at the split prototype [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_idp58609016.html)
you will notice the default parameter at the end !

So now in your call use an explicit `token_compress_off` for the last param and it will be ok.

```
split(tokenList, text, is_any_of(","), token_compress_off);
```